# Android how to keep other notifications on the notification tray after taping one notification

Tags: android, cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging, phonegap, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm using FCM notifications to send notifications and when I send multiple notifications for the same user they are received separately on the notification tray and when the user click in one of them the application opens. The problem is when the application is closed the others notifications that were not clicked are dismissed.

Is there any way to keep the others until they are clicked or manually  removed from the tray by the user?

Send code:

```
{"registration_ids":["xxx"]
,  "data": 
    {   "notId":1295603 
                 , "message" : "Message 1"
                 , "title" : "New Message Example"
                 , "data1" : "196901"
                 , "data2" : "2"
    } 
}

{"registration_ids":["xxx"]
 , "data": 
    {   "notId":1295604 
                 , "message" : "Message 2"
                 , "title" : "New Message Example 2"
                 , "data1" : "19777"
                 , "data2" : "2"
    } 
}

{"registration_ids":["xxx"]
 , "data": 
    {   "notId":1295605 
                 , "message" : "Message 3"
                 , "title" : "New Message Example 3"
                 , "data1" : "19778"
                 , "data2" : "3"
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you please send FireBaseMessageing class

Comment: Sorry I do not know what the "FireBaseMessageing class" is, where do I find this? Is it a firebase class or is the class that sends the notification?

Comment: Yes please follow the firebase doc first before you search any where or any things

Comment: you need to see demo project for notification of firebase 

https://www.codementor.io/flame3/send-push-notifications-to-android-with-firebase-du10860kb

Comment: I followed the firebase docs, but this looks like a Android handler configuration.